# run a script in every aspx file

Tags: asp.net

How can I run a script in every aspx file?

This is what I want to be run at the beginning of every aspx file. How can I do that?

I dont want to copy and paste it in every file I have

```
   if (CUser.LoginID == "")
   {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to create a base page class which inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and runs this code in `Page_Load`.  Then, change each of your pages to inherit from the base page class.  Then, any time a page loads, it will execute `Page_Load` in both the base class and in the page class.

Probably a better way to do this, but slightly more complex, is to implement an [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx).  The idea behind an HttpModule is that it will intercept the request, do something custom, and then pass the request along as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use an [HTTP module](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985) for this.

HTTP modules are registered for a web application and receive events at certain points throughout the lifecycle of a request.

Since this looks to be related to site authentication, you could use the `AuthenticateRequest` event to check your `CUser.LoginID` property and redirect if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BasePage.cs class:

```
public class BasePage:System.Web.UI.Page
{

   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
   {
       if (CUser.LoginID == "")
       {
           Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
       }
   }
}
```

And then every aspx file change from:

```
public partial class pagename: System.Web.UI.Page
```

to

```
public partial class pagename: BasePage
```

and you are done. It should work fine for you. It works excellent for my user login tracking and redirecting if user is not logged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate a user on a page request, as your code suggest, you should check out asp.net form authentication.

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

If you want to run an arbitrary set of functions on every page request, you can either:

1) Create a base page that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page, override the OnInit method and stick your code in there. Make sure your pages now inherit from that new base page.

or

2) Modify the Global.asax.cs by adding your code in the Application_BeginRequest method.

Answer (score 0):

I could answer your question directly.  However, it is common practice to put the authentication redirect in the web.config.  It would be in a section like this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".SAMPLESITEAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" cookieless="UseCookies"></forms>
 </authentication>
```

The user would be redirected to the url listed in loginUrl.